# How to get values from a map and set them into a numpy matrix row?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, python-3.4

I have a numpy matrix that I want to fill with the results of a function. This function returns a map of integer values that will be maped into a row of the matrix.

The values returned by the function are like:

```
{1:6, 2:3, 3:2, 4:2, 5:1}
```

Then, I wrote the following code to fill in the values into the matrix:

```
results = np.empty((10, 5), dtype=int)

for i in range(10):
    result = method()
    for j in range(5):
        results[i, j] = result[j]
```

I want to know if there is a more properly/efficient way to do this with python?

Comment: #FIRST: this will crash... Numpy arrays start with a 0-index. "results[10,x]" will crash! #SECOND: you should change the "function" to return the values not as dict. It seems there are no gaps (1,2,3,4,5 are the keys in dict). No reason to use dict as sparse data-structure. This will just slow things down. # THIRD: results[i][j] should be results[i,j]!

Comment: You should clearly indicate if your dictionary keys start from 0 or 1.

Comment: sascha: Thank you, I have edited the question following your comments. Anand: The dictionary keys start from 1, but I can modify the function to return the information in another data structure if it is more convenient!

Comment: Well... if you have no gaps, why not produce a numpy array or list in method() and return this. results[i,:] = result[:] would then be possible! You see: it is important to know exactly what method() produces.

Comment: @Sascha: The method() returns the number of boxes required to cover a graph given a box length, where the box length is every value between 1 and the graph diameter. For that reason I thought it was clear to return a dictionary containing {box_length : number_of_boxes}. But I can also return a list, clarifying in the documentation that the index + 1 will correspond with the box size and the value in that position will be the number of boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get the values form your dictionary and then use `np.full` to create your expected matrix :

```
>>> d={1:6, 2:3, 3:2, 4:2, 5:1}
>>> vals=d.values()
>>> np.full((10,5),list(vals))
array([[ 6.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 6.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 6.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 6.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 6.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 6.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 6.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 6.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 6.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 6.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  1.]])
```

And if the `method` function returns different results in each iteration, you can use a list comprehension to create your matrix:

```
l = np.array([list(method().values()) for _ in range(1, 11)])
```

NOTE: Since your dictionary keys are sorted digits and in this case your keys have a sorted hash value, the `dict.values` method returns a sorted value based on your keys:

```
>>> list(map(hash, range (1 , 6)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If your keys are not sorted digits, you can make your method functions return an ordered dictionary using [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

But note that since `OrderedDict` is ordered by insertion, if that is what you want, you can use it. However if you want to order based on keys, you can use the following approach to get the values:

```
[map(dict.get, range(1, 6)) for _ in range(10)]
```

Comment: You would need to also include how you would adapt this method when a different dictionary is returned by `method()` for every row. Which seems to be OP's case.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Since that it doesn't pass any argument to `method`  the result is one dict every time.

Comment: My guess is that `method()` is just a simple example OP used to indicate that he is getting the dict from a method everytime in the iteration , the actual method and its call may be lot different. Though I would let OP clarify this.

Comment: @Omid This assumes that there are no side-effects. Method() can have it's own state / e.g. random-generator!

Comment: Your second method is the same as the deleted answer, which would not work because - *You cannot rely on result.values() to return the result in the order 1 - 5 , because result is a dictionary and it does not have any order.*

Comment: @AnandSKumar Check out the note.

Comment: @Omid While this assumption about beeing sorted when keys are integers might work (for now!), this is not recommended at all. If the devs would change the hash-function used internally, this code would be broken. And because python defines this as "unordered", these kind of changes are not impossible!

Comment: @sascha As I said in my edit, the solution is tailored to this specific situation

Comment: And what is the specific situation? Did he tell you that he is using the Python-Interpreter Version X on this platform? Well... A new interpreter-version might break this!

Comment: The specific situation: The dict keys are ordered digits

Comment: And the approach with OrderedDict... It's ordered by insertion-time, not key-values! Again: new assumptions are needed about method's behaviour!

Comment: @sascha Yes, you are right about the OrderedDict. Check out the update.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make a couple of assumptions.

`method()` returns a different dictionary with each call, so you do need to iterate over the rows of `results`.

dictionary keys are not necessarily in numeric order, so we need to use `d.keys()`.

We are both working with Python3, so `keys` and `values` return iterables.  So I'll construct the arrays with `fromiter` (or `np.array(list(d.keys())`)

```
d={1:6, 2:3, 3:2, 4:2, 5:1}
results=np.empty((4,5), int)  # np.zeros better?
for i in range(results.shape[0]):
    result = d # method() 
    ind = np.fromiter(d.keys(), int)-1
    val = np.fromiter(d.values(), int)
    results[i, ind] = val
```

So the main difference from your code is that I make the array assignment one row at a time.